# Button1 not being clicked on startup

Tags: c#, winforms, button, visual-studio-express

I am having an issue with my WinForm application.

Below I have my code for my button that I want to click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do code.
    }
```

Now I want to run the program on start up, so I have this code below:

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }
```

But this does not work. It has red lines under the words: "sender", "EventArgs e"

What am I doing wrong, Please help me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to click button that way you should do:

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button1.PerformClick();
}
```

Second,
it is not a good idea to do it anyway, better approach is to create common method that is call in button_click event and form_load event.